# SQL Query Date Range in Multiple Years

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to get all sales in a certain range (first/last 2 weeks of a month) across multiple years. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM sales_history.transactions WHERE 
TRANS_DATE BETWEEN LIKE '%-04-01' AND LIKE '%-04-14'
```

The above of course doesn't work. `TRANS_DATE` is a DATE type.

I thought of doing something like

```
SELECT * FROM sales_history.transactions WHERE 
TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2007-04-01' AND '2007-04-14' OR 
TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2008-04-01' AND '2008-04-14' OR 
TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2009-04-01' AND '2009-04-14'
```

But it seems like there should be an easier way to do that and the more years I need the more of a pain it is. Ideally, I'd like to be able to define the start year and end year but I could make to with a straight wildcard on the year and get the data from all years in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  * FROM sales_history.transactions WHERE
MONTH(TRANS_DATE)=4 AND DAY(TRANS_DATE) BETWEEN 1 AND 14
```

Good luck :D